# Python: Multiprocessing Map takes longer to complete last few processes

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

In Python, I'm trying to run 150-200 processes. I have these 150 things in an array, and I've split this array up into multiple arrays of 10 elements each.

Now, I run a Multiprocessing Map, with 10 elements at a time. Once all 10 are complete, we go onto the next 10, and so on.

Now, the problem: The ninth and tenth process are almost ALWAYS slower than the rest. Is there a reason for that? Am I not doing this the most efficient way?

** I won't be able to share the code for this. So do you have any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you happen to have 4 or 8 processor cores?

Comment: A Core i7 Processor with 4 cores.
However, from what I've heard, it could use 4 cores as 8? Is that true?
Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, the i7s do hyper-threading to have 8 virtual cores, so that *might* be the reason.

Comment: So, would there be a way to fix that?

Comment: Well yes, using 8 instead of 10 parallel processes.

Comment: Thank you! It seemed to work!

Comment: There's a new problem: I can run the script 3 times, and it works fine, but when I run it the fourth time, the same problem arises. Any ideas?

Comment: Are all your elements to be processed supposed to be processed in an equivalent duration ? Or maybe some elements require an harder computation ? (or to wait from from a remote answer, etc. ?). In addition to setting the number of process to 8, did you try other multiprocessing methods such as `imap_unordered` to see if you have the same issue ?

Comment: Or is it possible that you are starting to be short of RAM at the end of your run, causing it dumping on hard drive (and generating a delay ?)

Comment: I haven't yet tried the other methods, but I will, thanks, but no, it's not a RAM issue, I have 64 GB of RAM, and I have 55 GB available during the process.

Comment: Well, I tried out `imap_unordered`, and it worked better, I can run it ~10 times, smoothly, but then it gets VERY slow after that (in fact, it can take up to 100 seconds to complete all 150). But yes, it does wait for a response from IBM Watson servers, which usually return within a second or two.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way `Pool.map` distributes the data among the workers. Use `chunksize=1` as a parameter, i.e. `map(...,..., chunksize=1)`.

A similar problem is explained in:
[python multiprocessing map mishandling of last processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221268/python-multiprocessing-map-mishandling-of-last-processes)

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up